# How can I find out the close-vote reasons for my question?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, flags

Suppose I have asked a question and someone votes for closing it. The thing is I just can see the number of close-votes ("close(3)") to my question. But I can't find the reason, why they voted for close.

But if I knew the reason, I could edit my question and correct it.

Same thing is true, if someone flagged my answer, comment or question. How do I find out, what the reason is?

Comment: Perhaps the case is different on SO, on SF 99.999% of the time it's a short, vague, open-ended question.

Comment: Unless it's blatantly obvious why a question should be closed, I normally leave a comment.  Read the comments.  For that matter, read the FAQ, and you should have a good idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you get enough reputation to close, you'll be able to see the voted reasons. If the question gets closed, the most voted reason will be stated bellow your question.

To know if your post was flagged, you'd need to be over 10k rep points, and only mods can see comment flags.

Remember that questions can be reopened, so improve it anyway, and people will vote to reopen.

Comment: Note it only takes [250 rep](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq) to close vote on your own questions, so you can see that relatively quickly.

Comment: Having to go to close your own question (which only some users can do in the first place) to see the reasons other gave is bad UX and GUI design. And that is an understatement. Hiding the reason for the close votes just makes it less likely that the question will be improved accordingly. What is the reason to hide the, uh, reasons?